# Why is JSON::XS Not Generating Valid UTF-8?

Tags: json, perl, utf-8

I'm getting some corrupted JSON and I've reduced it down to this test case.

```
use utf8;
use 5.18.0;
use Test::More;
use Test::utf8;
use JSON::XS;

BEGIN {
    # damn it
    my $builder = Test::Builder->new;
    foreach (qw/output failure_output todo_output/) {
        binmode $builder->$_, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
    }
}

foreach my $string ( 'Deliver «French Bread»', '日本国' ) {
    my $hashref = { value => $string };
    is_sane_utf8 $string, "String: $string";
    my $json = encode_json($hashref);
    is_sane_utf8 $json, "JSON: $json";
    say STDERR $json;
}
diag ord('»');

done_testing;
```

And this is the output:

```
utf8.t .. 
ok 1 - String: Deliver «French Bread»
not ok 2 - JSON: {"value":"Deliver Â«French BreadÂ»"}

#   Failed test 'JSON: {"value":"Deliver Â«French BreadÂ»"}'
#   at utf8.t line 17.
# Found dodgy chars "<c2><ab>" at char 18
# String not flagged as utf8...was it meant to be?
# Probably originally a LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK char - codepoint 171 (dec), ab (hex)
{"value":"Deliver «French Bread»"}    
ok 3 - String: 日本国
ok 4 - JSON: {"value":"æ¥æ¬å½"}
1..4
{"value":"日本国"}
# 187
```

So the string containing guillemets («») is valid UTF-8, but the resulting JSON is not. What am I missing? The `utf8` pragma is correctly marking my source. Further, that trailing 187 is from the diag. That's less than 255, so it almost looks like a variant of the old Unicode bug in Perl. (And the test output still looks like crap. Never could quite get that right with Test::Builder).

Switching to `JSON::PP` produces the same output.

This is Perl 5.18.1 running on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Further testing reveals that JSON::XS *seems* to create corrupted output on all characters from 127 to 255.

Answer (score 13):

`is_sane_utf8` doesn't do what you think it does. You're suppose to pass strings you've decoded to it. I'm not sure what's the point of it, but it's not the right tool. If you want to check if a string is valid UTF-8, you could use

```
ok(eval { decode_utf8($string, Encode::FB_CROAK | Encode::LEAVE_SRC); 1 },
   '$string is valid UTF-8');
```

---

To show that JSON::XS is correct, let's look at the sequence `is_sane_utf8` flagged.

```
          +--------------------- Start of two byte sequence
          |    +---------------- Not zero (good)     
          |    |     +---------- Continuation byte indicator (good)
          |    |     |
          v    v     v
C2 AB = [110]00010 [10]101011

             00010     101011 = 000 1010 1011 = U+00AB = «
```

The following shows that JSON::XS produces the same output as Encode.pm:

```
use utf8;
use 5.18.0;
use JSON::XS;
use Encode;

foreach my $string ('Deliver «French Bread»', '日本国') {
    my $hashref = { value => $string };
    say(sprintf("Input: U+%v04X", $string));
    say(sprintf("UTF-8 of input: %v02X", encode_utf8($string)));

    my $json = encode_json($hashref);
    say(sprintf("JSON: %v02X", $json));
    say("");
}
```

Output (with some spaces added):

```
Input: U+0044.0065.006C.0069.0076.0065.0072.0020.00AB.0046.0072.0065.006E.0063.0068.0020.0042.0072.0065.0061.0064.00BB
UTF-8 of input:                     44.65.6C.69.76.65.72.20.C2.AB.46.72.65.6E.63.68.20.42.72.65.61.64.C2.BB
JSON: 7B.22.76.61.6C.75.65.22.3A.22.44.65.6C.69.76.65.72.20.C2.AB.46.72.65.6E.63.68.20.42.72.65.61.64.C2.BB.22.7D

Input: U+65E5.672C.56FD
UTF-8 of input:                     E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD
JSON: 7B.22.76.61.6C.75.65.22.3A.22.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.22.7D
```

Answer (score 4):

JSON::XS is generating valid UTF-8, but you're using the resulting UTF-8 encoded byte strings in two different contexts that expect character strings.

### Issue 1: Test::utf8

Here are the two main situations when `is_sane_utf8` will fail:

1. You have a miscoded character string that had been decoded from a UTF-8 byte string as if it were Latin-1 or from double encoded UTF-8, **or** the character string is perfectly fine and looks like a *potentially* "dodgy" miscoding (using the terminology from its docs).
2. You have a *valid* UTF-8 byte string containing the encoded code points U+0080 through U+00FF, for example `«French Bread»`.

The `is_sane_utf8` test is intended only for character strings and has the documented potential for false negatives.

### Issue 2: Output Encoding

All of your non-JSON strings are character strings while your JSON strings are UTF-8 encoded byte strings, as returned from the JSON encoder. Since you're using the `:encoding(UTF-8)` PerlIO layer for TAP output, the character strings are being implicitly encoded to UTF-8 with good results, while the byte strings containing JSON are being double encoded. STDERR however does not have an `:encoding` PerlIO layer set, so the encoded JSON byte strings look good in your `warn`ings since they're already encoded and being passed straight out.

Only use the `:encoding(UTF-8)` PerlIO layer for IO with character strings, as opposed to the UTF-8 encoded byte strings returned by default from the JSON encoder.